# ASP.NET Core MVC: Create Post associated with Author previously create on another View

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm developing a demo app using ASP.NET Core MVC + EF Core.

1. I have two model classes: Author and BlogPost;
2. The relationship between them is One (Author) to Many (BlogPost);
3. I'd like to create an Author (using View "AuthorForm.cshtml") and then immediately be redirected to BlogPost View ("BlogPostForm.cshtml") **using the reference of the Author created as reference of the BlogPost to be created. Thus, I won't need to select Author to create a BlogPost**

Comment: No clear what is the problem you are facing , do you have any code you have implement ?

Comment: @NanYu I just edited my question. Please check it.

Comment: Once you create the author ,just pass the id to  BlogPostForm controller/action , what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: But I don't know the ID yet because it is generated by EF. And I don't know how to pass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core will help fill the value of identity column after `SaveChangesAsync` function .For exmaple :

Author.cs:

```
public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    public List<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
}
```

BlogPost.cs:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int BlogPostId { get; set; }
    public string BlogPostName { get; set; }


    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

In create author action EF Core will help fill the AuthorId after saving :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("AuthorId,AuthorName")] Author author)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(author);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        //here you will get id
        var id = author.AuthorId;

        //redirect to another action with parameter 
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index),new { id=id});
    }
    return View(author);
}
```

Then you will redirect to another action/view with parameter as above code shows .

Comment: @AyodArune , please mark my reply as answer by clicking the green check button which may help others who meet same problem